# Postgres incremental backups per db (not per cluster)

Tags: postgresql, backup

According to the WAL Point-in-time recovery and incremental backup documentation, pg_basebackup and wals are used to take backups and incremental backups of a running PostgreSQL cluster.

Is there a way to take incremental backups per database instead of the whole cluster ?

Thanks !

Comment: No. `pg_basebackup` and `WAL`s are cluster wide. You can use logical replication to replicate a particular database, but it does not offer point in time.

Comment: I was looking for db incremental backups.

Thank you !